# lotto program for android

Tags: android, arrays

Ok so im making a lotto program for my class. When I click generate it crashes, I dont know if I did the coding the right for the array when you click generate. I am a beginner but working on to be better. 
Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText min,max;
    TextView numbers1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        numbers1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
        max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maxinput);
        min = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mininput);

        ImageButton lotto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lotto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString()); i <= Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString()); i++)

            al.add(i);

        Random ran = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int x = al.remove(ran.nextInt(al.size()));
            al.get(x).toString();
        }   
        }       
        });  
   }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:187)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
com.edu.ext.lottoapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at    
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at    
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-15 12:19:46.562: E/AndroidRuntime(31065):    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What line of code does it crash on? Do you have a stack trace? Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: im new to this sorry, I dont have stack trace?

Comment: Go to Window -> show View -> other -> LogCat

Comment: Whats on MainActivity.java:42 ?

Comment: line 42?  al.get(x).toString();

Comment: The only thing I can see wrong with you code right now is you removing something from your ArrayList, and then calling `get` on that same index you removed. So its that random number turned out to be the end of the ArrayList then it would be out of bounds. The error does not match up with that though

Comment: Why did you change it to  al.get(x).toString()? Change it to numbers1.setText(al.get(x).toString());

Comment: ok well i ran it again and this time the log cat display MainActivity:41 which is,int x = al.remove(ran.nextInt(al.size()));

Answer (score 0):

You can't set Integers to a TextView.
Do something like this:

```
numbers1.setText(al.get(x + ""));
```

Comment: @GabeSechan yeah or this: `String.valueOf(x)`

Comment: @Ahmad Yes you can set Integers to `TextView`. Please look at the docs, `setText` has a few different overloaded versions of itself that take different parameters, one of which is integers. Heres a link as well. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

Comment: @Andy the only thing I can find is this: setText(int resid), but this take an resource ID as a parameter. Correct me if I am wrong, but I did not came across such a method :)

Comment: Well idk what to tell you but I am sure as there is day that `setText()` can most definitely take an int (or Integer) :) Go ahead try it. You can call me out on it if Android tells you otherwise

Comment: @Andy just to be sure I tested it - It crashed. Like said the only int param setText() takes is a resource

Comment: Hmm, then my app must be god, because I've been setting ints in `setText` for a while! :O What API level are you testing against?